# multiple laravel and nextjs together on apache

Tags: laravel, apache, next.js

I have multiple sites in subfolders, some with laravel, some with nextjs, on an apache server.
I have these folders:

- /var/www/html/my_sites/website (nextjs site)
- /var/www/html/my_sites/another_website (nextjs site)
- /var/www/html/my_sites/laravel_site (laravel site)
- /var/www/html/my_sites/another_laravel_site (laravel site)

I am trying to configure it. This is the apache file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/my_sites"
    ServerName my_sites.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/my_sites">
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8001/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This config file works if I navigate to `my_sites.com/website`, but I get 404 nextjs error if I navigate to `my_sites.com` (I do not expect nextjs error if I navigate to main url, I expect apache error).

I tried with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/my_sites"
    ServerName my_sites.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/my_sites">
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location "/website"> # <---- HERE
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8001/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I get 404 when I navigate to `my_sites.com/website`.
I also tried with an alias, something like:

```
Alias my_sites.com/website
```

without success.